# How to recursively copy files while removing part of the path

Tags: bash

I have a hundreds of image files in a structure like this:

path/to/file/100/image1.jpg

path/to/file/9999/image765.jpg

path/to/file/333/picture2.jpg

I'd like to remove the 4th part of the path (100,9999,333, ...) so that I get this:

path/to/file/image1.jpg

path/to/file/image765.jpg

path/to/file/picture2.jpg

In this case the image file names have no duplicates and the the target directory could be named entirely different if this makes things easier (e.g. target could be "another/path/to/the/images/image1.jpg"

The solution might be some combination of find/cut/rename command.

How can I do this in bash?

Comment: This has been answered many times before on stackoverflow and on other sites. What have you tried to solve the problem? I'm missing some research and code attempts in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have "hundreds" of files, it's quite possible that you don't need to do anything special, and can just write:

```
mv path/to/file/*/*.jpg path/to/file/
```

But depending on the number of files and lengths of their names, this may turn out to be more than the kernel will let you pass to a single command, in which case you may need to write a `for`-loop instead:

```
for file in path/to/file/*/*.jpg ; do
    mv "$file" path/to/file/
done
```

(Of course, this assumes you have `mv` on your path. There's no Bash builtin for renaming a file, so any approach will depend on what else is available on your system. If you don't have `mv`, you'll need to adjust the above accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ruakh's solution if it will work, but if you need to explicitly test for those numeric directories, here's an alternative.

I'm just using `echo` to pipe the list of names in, and to show the `mv` at the end, but you could use `find` (example in a comment) and remove the `echo` on the `mv` to make it live.

```
IFS=/ 
echo "path/to/file/100/image1.jpg
path/to/file/9999/image765.jpg
path/to/file/333/picture2.jpg" |
#   find path/to/file -name "*.jpg" |
while read -r orig
do this=""
   read -a line <<< "$orig" 
   for sub in "${line[@]}"
   do  if [[ "$sub" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
       then continue
       else this="$this$sub/"
       fi
   done
   old="${line[*]}"
   echo mv "$old" "${this%/}" 
done
mv path/to/file/100/image1.jpg  path/to/file/image1.jpg
mv path/to/file/9999/image765.jpg  path/to/file/image765.jpg
mv path/to/file/333/picture2.jpg path/to/file/picture2.jpg
```